# How to program Logitech function keys?

Tags: keyboard, logitech, function-keys

most Logitech keyboards have **function keys** and by pressing the <kbd>FN</kbd> button and one of <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> they perform some specific function.

In Windows, for example with "**SetPoint**", you can change their functionality.  As an example :

[image: setpoint screen]

---

I'm not talking about changing shortcuts. some of these function keys (common keys like `Home`, `email`, etc..) are known in Ubuntu. for example ubuntu known <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> as `HomePage`, but some special function keys like [in my case] `Flip`, `Show Desktop` and other functions that designed for windows, known as combination of <kbd>Super</kbd> with another key. for example ubuntu known [in my case] <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, that represent `show desktop`, as <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

The question is *"How could I define them in ubuntu as a new key?"* Is it possible?

---

P.S:

1. I read related questions and their answers, but I didn't get my
   answer.
2. I emphasize that I'm not talking about keyboard shortcuts
   and I'm actually talking about defining a new keyboard key type
3. And sorry for my bad english xD

Comment: you can probably use xmodmap to remap existing keys to "new" keys, for example F13.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, to put it in simple words, you want to create a custom key (be it a combination of keys).

If that's the case and you are using Ubuntu Precise go to **SYSTEM SETTINGS** then **KEYBOARD** and then hit the **SHORTCUTS** tab.

If the feature you want isn't in the list just go to the **bottom on the list** on the **left hand side** and click **CUSTOM SHORTCUTS**.

You can then click the little **+** symbol at the **bottom of the screen** to add a new custom shortcut. Then type in the **Shortcut name followed by the command** to invoke it (really depends and what you want to do). You'll have to research the command you need to start or invoke the application or task you want to do. After typing in the command hit **OK**.

You will now see the shortcut created in the list. **Towards the right** it will have the word **DISABLED**. click on the word **DISABLED** and then click the **key or combination of keys** you want to use to activate this shortcut (the command) you created.

> ***for example**: if I want to create a key shortcut to open www.google.com in the browser and want to call the shortcut CHROME. I
>   then want it to run when I hit CTRL + W, I would do the following **in
>   the SYSTEM SETTINGS > KEYBOARD > SHORTCUTS section***
>
> NAME: **CHROME**
>
> COMMAND: **chromium-browser http://www.google.com**
>
> - I would then hit the **OK** button
> - Then, I would click on the word **DISABLED** that appears the right
>     of the shortcut named CHROME
> - After clicking on the word DISABLED I would hit **CTRL** and **W**
>     key together.

You can use the **SUPER** key or any key on your keyboard. I've tested this on my system with a Logitech (being a Logitech Fan lol).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned in my question, I'm not talking about shortcuts or how to creating them.
I tried to clear my problem with examples.
for example, in windows for lock screen you could use `super + L` and by pressing `lock screen` button you actually pressed that combination, but in setPoint you can change this task as you see in image I posted. so I think `lock screen` and other special keys have types like `Email`, `Next` or `play` that ubuntu can't understand it. So I want to define for example `LockScreen` key type and assign it to that button.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. lol Tried using my VoiP key on my Logitech Keyboard and it doesn't recognise it. Hummm will research about this and post the answer here if I manage to understand something about that. I'm pretty sure there is a way.

Comment: I found this (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) but I'm a little confused xD

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I managed to understand that you can set up these special keys if you know their scancode for example this link http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-6.html show scancodes for limited keyboards. Can you provide me with your keyboard model? I can't seem to find mine over the internet but I am sure there is a software to find out the key scancode

Comment: This forum might help you. There is a list of software you can use to identify what code the key is using http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/3129/  I am still investigating this.

Comment: thanks, I have a MK520 combo. keyboard model is k520.
if you're able to post another answer, post it in another answer, if not please edit this answer to set it as accepted answer