# How can I map my Logitech gamepad to the keyboard?

Tags: 13.04, logitech, gamepad

I recently downloaded Steam and bought the HL1 bundle, as well as a few other games through Steam and Desura. I would like to use my Logitech F310 instead of the keyboard and mouse, but I can't seem to find any application to map those keys to buttons on my gamepad. Can anyone help out?

Comment: You might be able to map it in the individual game settings. I am not familiar with steam, but most games have that option.

Comment: Try to see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/170860/156684).